# How to delete rows in attribute table of a shapefile based on specific condition?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cursor

I want to delete certain rows in a shapefile if field `ID` is equal to certain number (say 2).

Below is what I am trying:

```
import arcpy    
shape="C:\Users\Data\Loc.shp"
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(shape)
for row in rows:
    if row.Id==2:
        row.Id=row.Id.replace("row.ID", "")
        rows.updateRow(row) 

del row 
del rows
```

I am using ArcGIS 10

Comment: Do you need to use arcpy? Do the two feature classes have some attribute in common? If the answer to questions 1 is no and yes for question 2, you can try to join the attributes from B to A and then work with `select by attributes` selections and manually delete your unwanted entries.

Comment: I did it in ArcGIS the same way you wrote, but how to do it using ArcPY.

Comment: If you want to do it using arcpy, please provide some code or ideas you've had. We can hardly provide you with the code from scratch...

Comment: @dru87 I have updated my question and included the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following is the preferred method (ArcGIS version > 10.1) for deleting specific rows using the `deleteRow()` method and the `da` data access module:

```
import arcpy

shp = r'C:\path\to\your\shapefile.shp'

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(shp, "some_field") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] == 2:
            cursor.deleteRow()
```

---

The following method can be used for ArcGIS versions <= 10.1.

```
import arcpy

shp = r"C:\path\to\your\shapefile.shp"

rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(shp, "", "", "some_field")
for row in rows:
    if row.some_field == 2:
        rows.deleteRow(row)
del row
del rows
```